# How to make participant input appear on screen and be wrapped (Psychtoolbox)

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I’m trying to create a rectangle box on screen in PTB wherein the participant can type text that is wrapped inside this box.  So I would like to get the string input to be drawn on screen while typing in a rectangular box where the text input is wrapped to avoid it continuing outside the border of this box. I have been searching for a while now and haven’t found anything that works or anyone who did this before. I assume I might be overlooking something very simple.

I have tried using:

```
% Textbox
Screen('FrameRect',window, white, [300 300 1600 600],4);    
message = [‘Your comments: ‘];
replySubj = Ask(window, message, white, black, 'GetChar',[300 225 1600 600]);
```

The response input is nicely drawn on screen while typing, but only on one line that is not wrapped when I reach the side of the box, or even my screen. Is their a way to wrap the text (e.g. by integrating WrapString.m) so it stays inside a specified rectangle on screen, and continues to a new line if the text is too long for one line?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `GetEchoString` function, it does the following upon each character strike (to the best of my understanding of how the display is managed):

- if it is `Ctrl-C`, `Enter`, or `Return`: exit;
- if it is `Backspace`, issue command to re-draw the previous full string (prompt + user input) with the same colour as the background to erase it ; then remove the last character from the stored full string;
- else append the character to the stored full string.

Then issue the command to draw the resulting updated full string in the specified colour, and finally update the screen following the previous commands, with the option `dontclearset` to `1` (incremental drawing, cf. `Screen('Flip', windowPtr, 0, 1)` call).

To add wrapping capabilities, we can thus modify `GetEchoString` as follows:

- comment out the re-drawing commands when `Backspace` is hit, simply updating the stored string (see below);
- add a call to `WrapString` on the updated string to wrap it;
- used `DrawFormattedText` to issue command to display the wrapped string;
- finally, call `Screen('Flip', windowPtr)` that is update the screen with `dontclearset` to `0` (default).

The relevant part of the function are now thus:

```
% adapted from PTB3 GetEchoString
while true
    if useKbCheck
        char = GetKbChar(varargin{:});
    else
        char = GetChar;
    end
    if isempty(char)
        string = '';
        break;
    end
    switch (abs(char))
        case {13, 3, 10}
            % ctrl-C, enter, or return
            break;
        case 8
            % backspace
            if ~isempty(string)
                % Remove last character from string:
                string = string(1:length(string)-1);
            end
        otherwise
            string = [string, char];
    end

    output = [msg, ' ', string];
    output=WrapString(output,maxNumChar);
    DrawFormattedText(windowPtr,output,x,y,textColor,[],0,0,vLineSpacing);
    Screen('Flip',windowPtr);
end
```

Where `maxNumChar` and `vLineSpacing` are to be defined depending on your needs.

This will take care of the horizontal wrapping of the text, while keeping the `Backspace` function working. Note however that you could still overflow vertically if the whole screen is filled.